# How to handle popup or window in angular website by using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webdriver, protractor

i have tried with below code but its not working. Even that code not switch to popup window.

```
it('should switch to popUp\'s handle', function () {
        console.log("ASDASD");
        var handlePromise = browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles();
        handlePromise.then(function (handles) {
            // parentHandle = handles[0];
            var popUpHandle = handles[1];
            browser.driver.switchTo().window(popUpHandle);
            element(by.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper')]")).click();
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 1 handle by the time that code executes?  `console.log('Handles', handles.length);`  Also you dont need to reference `driver`.  Just do `browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);`

Comment: console.log('Handles', handles.length); also tried , thing is that script is not switched at popup window.

Comment: So `handles.length` returns `2`?